# Smooth pixels while rotating sprite

Tags: android, sprites, andengine, antialiasing

I just started with andengine, so this maybe gonna be silly question.
How to make my sprites more smooth while I rotate them? Or maybe it because this is screenshot from tablet?

[image]

Thanks JohnEye it works:

[image]

Just need to change my BitmapTextureAtlas from:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas carAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),100, 63);
```

to:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas carAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),100, 63, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
```

Comment: I don't use Andengine, and I couldn't find the info in a search but you'll want to us antialiasing for this. If it doesn't offer that natively you can change the opengl texture calls to use nearest instead of linear. You may also try using higher resolution sprites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TextureOptions settings are likely to be the cause, see the call that you use for creating your TextureAtlas. Try the different TextureOptions and see which one you like the most. For more information, see the [related thread on the AndEngine forum](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/compare-4-type-of-textureoptions-t805.html).